# generator called at the wrong time (keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I use `fit_generator()` in keras 2.0.2 with batch size 10 and steps 320 because I have 3209 samples for training. Before the first epoch begins, the generator was called 11 times, showing:

```
Train -- get ind: 0 to 10
    ...    
Train -- get ind: 100 to 110
```

Then, after the first batch (1/320), it prints out `Train -- get ind: 110 to 120`, but I think it should be `Train -- get ind: 0 to 10`. Is my implementation for the `train_generator()` function incorrect? Or why am I having this issue?

Here is my code for the generator:

```
EPOCH = 10
x_train_img = img[:train_size] # shape: (3209,512,512)
x_test_img = img[train_size:]  # shape: (357,512,512)

def train_generator():
    global x_train_img

    last_ind = 0

    while 1:
        x_train = x_train_img[last_ind:last_ind+BATCH_SIZE]
        print('Train -- get ind: ',last_ind," to ",last_ind+BATCH_SIZE)
        last_ind = last_ind+BATCH_SIZE
        x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
        x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 512, 512, 1)) 
        yield (x_train, x_train)
        if last_ind >= x_train_img.shape[0]:
             last_ind = 0

def test_generator():
     ...

train_steps = x_train_img.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE #320
test_steps = x_test_img.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE   #35

autoencoder.fit_generator(train_generator(), 
                steps_per_epoch=train_steps, 
                epochs=EPOCH,
                validation_data=test_generator(),
                validation_steps=test_steps,
                callbacks=[csv_logger] )
```

A better? way of writing the generator:

```
def train_generator():
    global x_train_img

    while 1:
        for i in range(0, x_train_img.shape[0], BATCH_SIZE):
            x_train = x_train_img[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]
            print('Train -- get ind: ',i," to ",i+BATCH_SIZE)
            x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
            x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 512, 512, 1)) 
            yield (x_train, x_train)
```

Comment: I assume the indentation of the conditional `if last_ind >= ...` is wrong?

Comment: @jdehesa, at first, I did not have it, but I added it after I got `CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM` or `expected (x,y), but got None` error, because the last_ind would end (yield empty array) before the epoch can complete the 320 steps required.

Comment: Right, but I meant that I suppose the conditional should be _inside_ the `while 1:` loop, not _after_ it, right?

Comment: @jdehesa Apologies. It is inside. I copy-pasted and format changed. Sorry.

Comment: Okay thanks, yeah that's what I assumed but just making sure it was not an error in the original code.

Comment: I don't see what bothrs you. If it trained the first epoch on samples 0 through 110, then the second will start from sample 110, since after the yield you don't reset the counter.

Comment: @gionni, what bothers me is that the training samples for that epoch runs out before it finishes the epoch. I know that it just takes the samples from the next epoch, but this is not how it should be and this could lead to further errors.

Comment: Ok, read the question again, now I see there's something wrong. So basically at the first epoch the generator is called 11 times (samples 0 through 110) right? but you'd expect it to be called just once? Just trying to understand the desired output, sorry if the questions sound stupid

Comment: @gionni, Yes, that's the problem. First epoch is called 11 times, but the ones after are called just once, but it should be called once each epoch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `fit_generator()` uses a `max_queue_size=10`.
So what you've observed is that:

1. Before the epoch starts, your generator yields 10 batches to fill up the queue. That's samples 0 through 100.
2. Then, the epoch starts, and one batch is popped from the queue for modell fitting.
3. The generator yields a new batch to fill up the empty space in the queue. That's samples 100 through 110.
4. Then, the progress bar is updated. The progress `1/320` is printed on the screen.
5. Steps 2 and 3 are executed again, `get ind: 110 to 120` is printed.

So there's nothing wrong with this model fitting procedure. The first batch generated is indeed the first one used to fit the model. It's just that there's a queue hiding behind it, and the generator got called several times to fill up the queue, before the first model update happens.

Comment: I ve looked into the code too, and I think this answer is correct. You get the error without the if because the generator runs in parallel to the training. You can easily check this by setting `max_queue_size=1`

Comment: @gionni, @Yu-Yang, you guys are right. I tried setting `max_queue_size=1` and it fits the explanation. I will delete my previous comment to avoid confusion.